# How to close ModalPopupExtender on a button click from an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have added modalPopupExtender in my Page and inside that i am calling another page in Iframe. And on button Click i am doing some processing, i just want to know how can i close the modalPopUpExtender on submit click of that button.

My code is -

```
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="PP" 
                                    TargetControlID="btnCounceller" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                                    CancelControlID="btnclose">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="PP" runat="server" BackColor="white" Height="200px" Width="350px">
    <table class="style1">
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>
                   <iframe ID="ff" runat="server" frameborder="0" src="Order.aspx" style="width:350px; height:200px;"></iframe>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnclose" runat="server" Text="X" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </asp:Panel>
```

and My Order.aspx Contains

```
 <table>
        <tr>
           <td>First Name :</td>
           <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                    onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Now i just want to close my modalPopUp on click of Submit Button from IFrame

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:Panel ID="PP" runat="server" BackColor="white" Height="200px" Width="350px">
        <table class="style1">
             <tr>
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:Button ID="btnclose" runat="server" Text="X" OnClick="btnclose_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                <iframe ID="ff" runat="server" frameborder="0" src="Order.aspx" style="width:350px; height:200px;"></iframe>
                 </td>
                 </tr>
        </table>
      </asp:Panel>

Protected void btnclose_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
response.redirect("yourpage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: But it will open that page in Iframe only , it will not redirect to main page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery as below

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    $("#<%= btnclose.ClientID %>").click();
});
```

This will fire click event of your cancel control `btnclose` for the modal popup extender on clicking `btnSubmit` from your iframe. You need to find and replace the actual ID for your iframe button `btnSubmit`.